# SQLITE - combine a couples names (first and last name included)

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables: People and Clients. Here is a basic sample.

'People' columns:

```
 cliend_id|first_name|last_name
------------------------------
    1       Dan         Black
    1       Jenn        Black
    2       Rob         White
    2       Lisa        Green
```

'Clients' columns:

```
client_id|address
   1      43 address
   2      89 address
```

In the case where there is two partners (people) living in the same house (which in combination make a client), I am trying to combine the two to output something like "Black, Jenn & Dan"

I have the following

```
    SELECT 
      clients.address_google Address, 
      group_concat(people.last_name || ", " || people.first_name, " & ") Name
    FROM clients 
    INNER JOIN people ON people.client_id = clients.client_id
```

Which outputs a single line - Address and Name. My question is specific to the Name part.
If the last name is the same I would want "Black, Dan & Jenn"
If the last name is not the same, I would want "White, Rob & Green, Lisa"

Is there a way to test if the last name is the same, and if so omit it for the second person?

Comment: So you want 1 row as a result for all the clients?

Comment: (sorry having issues with line breaks) Looking for two rows:

ROW1:43 address|Black, Dan & Jenn -----------

ROW2:89 address|White, Rob & Green, Lisa

Answer (score 0):

As a starter: you need to add a `group by` clause to the query to make it a valid aggregation query.

Then: if there always is 1 or 2 personn at a given address (not more), as shown in your sample data, then an option is a conditional expression:

```
select 
    c.address_google address, 
    case when min(p.last_name) <> max(p.last_name)
        max(p.last_name) || ', ' || group_concat(p..first_name, ' & ')
        else group_concat(p.last_name || ', ' || p.first_name, ' & ') 
    end as name
from clients c
inner join people p on p.client_id = c.client_id 
group by c.address_google
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() window function to get the 1st of the clients that has a last_name same as others:

```
SELECT 
  c.address_google Address, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN p.rn = 1 THEN p.last_name || ", " ELSE '' END || p.first_name, " & ") Name
FROM clients c 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY client_id, last_name ORDER BY first_name) rn
  FROM people
) p ON p.client_id = c.client_id 
GROUP BY c.client_id, c.address_google;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4uRvnc1sp7CDDKoPr98M7k/0).
Results:

```
| Address    | Name                     |
| ---------- | ------------------------ |
| 43 address | Black, Dan & Jenn        |
| 89 address | Green, Lisa & White, Rob |
```